# Pinterest's Pinit.js

Tags: jquery, pinterest

I'm currently using the 'pinit' function on my portfolio website to allow my users to share my pictures on projects page.

The button works BUT I encounter 2 issues:
- my projects pictures are displayed as a slideshow throught jQuery Cycle, so the pinit function only propose to pin the visible pictures
- there's related projects thumbnails at the bottom of the page that the pinitfunction propose to pin as well, but I don't want to.

Here is a quick sketch to explain:

[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [casimages.com](http://nsa37.casimages.com/img/2015/08/24/150824124350281795.png))</sub>

Any idea?

Thank you for advance.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some code.

Comment: You could instead use individual pin it buttons on each image you want to be pinnable. That is probably the easiest solution. The pinit button won't pin elements with display:none or visibility:hidden.